# Rendering an array of components with seperate states in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

Okay! So questions similar to this have already been asked but the problem is that they don't solve my exact problem so please read the full question and consider looking at the code snippet pasted below before marking it as duplicate. So I have an array of objects `menuItems` which holds the props for another component `MenuItem`, and I'm trying to render that component `MenuItem` multiple times by iterating through that array "`menuItems`" and assigning unique props to it and then pushing it to another array called `items` and when this is done I'm placing this `items` array inside the return but somehow react is not rendering that array at all.

```
function Menu() {

    let items = [];

    const menuItems = [
        {
            imageName:'food-header-2.jpg',
            itemTitle:'Full breakfast for morning',
            itemPunchLine:'Some punchline',
            quantity:0,
        },
        {
            imageName:'pizza.jpg',
            itemTitle:'Cheeze pizza',
            itemPunchLine:'Some punchline',
            quantity:0,
        },
        {
            imageName:'burger.jpg',
            itemTitle:'Jumbo Burger',
            itemPunchLine:"Some punchline",
            quantity:0,
        },
        {
            imageName:'sandwich.jpg',
            itemTitle:'Veg SandWich',
            itemPunchLine:'Some punchline',
            quantity:0,
        },
        {
            imageName:'chocolate-shake.jpg',
            itemTitle:'Chocolate Shake',
            itemPunchLine:'Some punchline',
            quantity:0,
        },
    ]

    const useEffect(() => {

        menuItems.forEach((menuItem,index) => {
            items.push(
            <MenuItem key={index} title={menuItem.itemTitle} punchLine={menuItem.itemPunchLine} 
            quantity={menuItem.quantity} imageName={menuItem.imageName}
            />);
        }));

        
    };
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <div className="menu-holder">
                <div className="menu">
                    {items}                 
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`items` is a plain array. It's not a stateful value (i.e using `useState` hook). React will not re-render when this value changes.

Instead you should render the `menuItems` directly using `map` in your return statement:

```
 return(
    <div className="container">
        <div className="menu-holder">
            <div className="menu">
                {menuItems.map((menuItem,index) => 
                  <MenuItem
                    key={index} 
                    title={menuItem.itemTitle} 
                    punchLine={menuItem.itemPunchLine} 
                    quantity={menuItem.quantity}
                    imageName={menuItem.imageName}
                  />)}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

...

If you wanted to keep the `items` array for some reason, to follow this approach you need to convert it to react state.

You could achieve it like so:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const menuItems = [
  {
      imageName:'food-header-2.jpg',
      itemTitle:'Full breakfast for morning',
      itemPunchLine:'Some punchline',
      quantity:0,
  }
]

function Menu() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setItems(menuItems)
  }, [])

  return(
      <div className="container">
          <div className="menu-holder">
              <div className="menu">
                {items.map((menuItem,index) => 
                  <MenuItem
                    key={index} 
                    title={menuItem.itemTitle} 
                    punchLine={menuItem.itemPunchLine} 
                    quantity={menuItem.quantity}
                    imageName={menuItem.imageName}
                  />)}
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  )
}
```

However if you know the `menuItems` at render time, it would be more efficient to set the initial state to this straight away (rather than setting it after render in the `useEffect` hook:

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState(menuItems);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly fine but then I tried to use the same `array.map` inside the `useEffect` hook and then try to render the array it stops working and react throws an error `Objects are not valid as React Child` I want to ask why is it so? and how does `map` makes the array stateful?

Comment: I've extended the answer, to try and show the patterns you should use. `map` does not make a value stateful in React, it is simply a way to iterate over an array and return a new array.

Answer (score 2):

For React to watch for state changes you can use `useState` hook to track the change in the state of the array.

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([])
```

Comment: Do you mean I should do `setItems([...items, newItem])` inside the `menuItems.forEach` loop?